# How can I find the file that is currently used as a wallpaper in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop

How can I find the name (and path) to the desktop wallpaper file currently used by Windows 7? I followed the registry for the desktop wallpaper, which showed a file called "TranscodedWallpaper.jpg", but that's not what I want. Is there a way to find the original file which had been copied to "TranscodedWallpaper.jpg"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original file is stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General\WallpaperSource`.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the desktop and select customize, then you can click on "wallpaper" in the bottom left area of the window, which shows you (among others) the wallpaper that you currently have selected. Then you can again right click and select properties and get the path to the file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know how to do this, but my theme has too many pictures (more than 5000), so it's not practical to check them visually. Do you know another way?

Answer (score 1):

[BioniX Wallpaper Changer](http://www.bionixwallpaper.com/) has a function called 'Restore wallpaper' (the button is located in 'Settings' tab).

To view the original wallpaper file name:

1. Set the Log to 'verbose' the 'Restore wallpaper' button .
2. Now you should see the name of the original in the log.

Note that you can set BioniX Wallpaper Changer to always show the name of the wallpaper directly on your desktop. This way you won't get lost again :)