# Looking for a past Wallpaper on windows 7

Tags: desktop-customization

I had a wallpaper on my computer but there was never a saved location for it it may have been transferred by usb or something because I cannot find it anywhere, is there a way to get a log of the names of past wallpapers or a folder of past wallpapers? The picture is very very sentimental to me any help would be appreciated

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/173397/how-can-i-find-the-file-that-is-currently-used-as-a-wallpaper-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

try the below location - it usually contains a copy of the recent wallpapers

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles
```